# Dictionary Comprehensions to filter text within the values

Tags: python, text, filter, contains, dictionary-comprehension

I have created the list of dictionaries (all_quotes_i) , and want to select the elements that contain quotes only from "Scotty Pelley"

```
all_quote_i = []  

#Each quote is given an index number
for idx, qte in enumerate(all_p):
    qte = all_p[idx].getText()
    all_quote_i.append({'Index': idx, 'Quote': qte})

print(all_quote_i[5:8])

> [{'Index': 5, 'Quote': 'Scott Pelley: (00:01)\nOn election night 2016,
> then President Barack Obama called Donald Trump at about three o’clock
> in the morning to congratulate him, even though Mr. Trump had lost the
> popular vote and took the electoral college by less than 1% in three
> states. Today, President Trump declines to accept the verdict of the
> voters despite losing by greater margins to President Elect Joe Biden.
> Mr. Obama hasn’t spoken of the election standoff until today. We spoke
> to the 44th president on the release of his new book, A Promised Land,
> a memoir of his early years and first term.'}, {'Index': 6, 'Quote':
> 'Speaker 2: (00:43)\nThe story will continue in a moment.'}, {'Index':
> 7, 'Quote': 'Scott Pelley: (00:48)\nWhat is your advice in this moment
> for President Trump?'}, {'Index': 8, 'Quote': 'Barack Obama:
> (00:54)\nWell, a president is a public servant. They are temporary
> occupants on the office by design. When your time is up, then it is
> your job to put the country first and think beyond your own ego and
> your own interests and your own disappointments. My advice to
> President Trump is if you want, at this late stage in the game to be
> remembered as somebody who put country first, it’s time for you to do
> the same thing.'}]
```

I want to use a list comprehension to select only the "Quote"(s) from Scott Pelly:
pelley_only = [v for k,v in  all_quote_i if v.startswith('Scott Pelley')]

Comment: You have posted a huge chunk of code, most of which does not seem relevant to what you're asking. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and create a minimal example of the problem you are trying to solve, so that others may be able to help you.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: I want to use a list comprehension to select only the "Quote"(s) from Scott Pelly: pelley_only = [v for k,v in all_quote_i if v.startswith('Scott Pelley')]

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
pelley_quotes = [quote["Quote"] for quote in quotes 
                 if quote["Quote"].startswith("Scott Pelley")]
```

If you want the full dictionary containing the quote, you can change `quote["Quote"]` to just `quote`

Comment: @nhandy No problem! Marking as a solution and upvoting is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I was able to "upvote" but I don't see how to mark your answer as a solution

Comment: @nhandy you can mark as solution by clicking the grey checkmark to the left side of my answer, underneath the upvote and downvote buttons. The mark should turn green.

Comment: My reputation score isn't high enough to move the vote count, but "was recorded."